# Using libVLC as a video decoder

Tags: c++, c, decode, libvlc

I'm attempting to use libVLC as a video decoder for a motion detection project. Previously I was using ffmpeg libraries, but some issues with Matroska files brought me here. Along with playing video back at the correct rate, I also want to be able to get one frame after another at the fastest rate my system can handle, as once the user sets up some parameters, I want the motion detection algorithm to run through the video as quickly as it can. My libVLC setup code looks like this (error handling and minor details omitted for brevity):

```
const char* vlc_argv[] =
{
    "--no-audio", /* skip any audio track */
};
libvlc_instance_t* inst = libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_argv) / sizeof(*vlc_argv), vlc_argv);
auto media = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, filename.c_str());
player = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(media);
libvlc_media_release(media);

// Needed to initialize the player ?
libvlc_media_player_play(player);
libvlc_media_player_pause(player);

fps = libvlc_media_player_get_fps(player);
length = libvlc_media_player_get_length(player);
width = libvlc_video_get_width(player);
height = libvlc_video_get_height(player);

// TODO: Add libvlc_video_set_callbacks to set up callbacks to render to memory buffer
```

However, I am left with the following questions:

1. Is there a more straightforward way to initialize the media player without starting playback besides calling `libvlc_media_player_play` then `libvlc_media_player_pause`?
2. All of the `get` functions (`fps, length, width, height`) all return zero. Do I need to do something like read the first frame to get these values, and if so, how am I supposed to know how large my decoded frame buffer must be?

Comment: Hi, just wondering, on which OS are you?

Comment: This was done in Windows, though I run Linux and Windows.

Comment: You could use transcoding to access unpaced frames. Here is my code for that: https://github.com/aleksas/libvlc-stream-grabber/blob/master/source/VlcStreamGrabber.cpp .

Comment: The problem I was having with ffmpeg was a user error. (At the time, I was unaware of pixel aspect ratios.) Unless there have been significant changes to libvlc, ffmpeg libraries are still probably better tools for decoding frames and manipulating them individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From a VLC developer](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?p=374573#p374573):

1. The regular playback system is really not meant for unpaced decoding. You'd need to use stream output, for which there is no programmable API as yet.
2. `get` calls are returning zero because you need to wait until the tracks are created.

Comment: `wait until the tracks are created` what does it mean